# multiple coefficients with python

Tags: python, combinatorics

Here is the problem:
Let there be 9 distinct objects, find all the ways of dividing it into groups of 2, 3 and 4.

Mathematically, the total number of division method can be expressed as 9!/2!3!4!

Here is what I have tried,

```
import itertools
def multiCoef(seta, n1, n2):
  seta = set(seta)
  for comba in itertools.combinations(seta, n1):
    comba = set(comba)
    for combb in itertools.combinations(seta-comba, n2):
      combb = set(combb)
      yield comba, combb, seta-comba-combb
```

You can try it with something like this, it runs pretty well:

```
>>> y = multiCoef(x, 2, 3)
>>> for i in y: print i
```

But once the number of groups gets bigger, this approach gets cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Comment: I understand the question. It's combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

See itertools.

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 2):

To find the number of ways to divide `(m+n+p)` items in group of `m,n,p`is first to divide the set in groups of `m` and then each of these groups divide by `n` followed by divide by `p`.

Now of ways to divide (m+n+p) items in groups of (n+p) is

==> <sup>(n+m+n)</sup>C<sub>n+p</sub>

==> (m+n+p)!/(m!*(n+p)!)

Now of ways to divide (n+p) items in groups of n is

==> <sup>(n+p)</sup>C<sub>n</sub>

==> (n+p)!/(n!*(p)!)

so <sup>(n+m+n)</sup>C<sub>m</sub> * <sup>(n+p)</sup>C<sub>n</sub> = (m+n+p)!/(m!*(n+p)!) * (n+p)!/(n!*(p)!)

==> (m+n+p)!/(m!*n!*p!)

To do the combinations we can use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Given m=4,n=3,p=2

Divide the Group into (n+p) = 5 items

```
>>> g1=(x for x in itertools.combinations(xrange(9),5))
```

Note:: You can leave it as a generator.

Divide each of these groups into subgroup of n items = 3 items

```
>>> groups=[(x,tuple(set(g)-set(x))) for g in g1 for x in itertools.combinations(g,3)]
```

Note:: tuple(set(g)-set(x)) would give you elements not is x i.e. the other part of the group

Size of the Group is

```
>>> len(groups)
1260
>>>
```

Now Validate

```
>>> factorial(9)/(factorial(2)*factorial(3)*factorial(4))
1260
```

Comment: I think you might have missed the point. g2 should be chosen from the remaining 5?

Comment: @CravingSpirit, Sorry missed it

Answer (score 1):

Once you have defined the function subsets(a,b) for enumerating all the subsets of size b in a

```
for i in subsets(mySet,2):
    for j in subsets(mySet.difference(i),3):
        for k in subsets(j.difference(k),4)
            print i,j,k
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a recursive generator that takes the range of numbers (`first` and `last`) and `avail`, the list of the desired set sizes. The assumption is that `sum(avail) == last - first + 1)`

In each iteration of the loop, the algorithm tries to assign first to one of the sets, and then generate all the assignments for `first + 1, ..., last`. The generate produces tuples of set assignments: the value in each position in the tuple identifies the set assignment for the corresponding index. In other words `t(k)` is the set assignment for `first+k`, a number in the range `0..len(avail)-1`

```
def generate(first, last, avail): 
   for index, n in enumerate(avail):
       if n == 0:
           continue
       new_avail = list(avail)
       new_avail[index]-=1
       if first < last:
           for d in generate(first + 1, last, new_avail):
               d = (inex,) + d
               yield d
       elif first == last:
           yield (index, )

for perm in generate(1, 9, [2, 3, 4]):
    print perm
```